# angular order by id desc

Tags: angular, sorting

I have a JSON file as below and I wanted to sort by desc using the id "37", "46" or "47". But I don't how is it possible to do because I'm accesing this data using "Object.keys(this.incident)" and I subscribe data this way :

```
`ngOnInit(): void {

Observable.timer(0,60000).flatMap(() => this.http.get<any>(this.dataUrl))
.subscribe(data => { this.incidents = data, console.log(data)});
}`
```

I would like to sort the data by using something similar to : 
`<div *ngFor="let incident of incidents | orderby">`

```
[
{"37":
  [{"NINJAOPS_MASTER":[]},
   {"NINJAOPS_EVENT_COLLECTION":[]},
   {"NINJAOPS_DIAGNOSIS":[]},
   {"NINJAOPS_DECISION":[]},
   {"NINJAOPS_REMEDIATION_AI":[]}]},

{"46":
  [{"NINJAOPS_MASTER": 
      [{"NINJAOPS_ID":"46",
        "BABYLON_REF":"8547",
        "EVENT_COLLECTION_STATUS":"1",
        "DIAGNOSIS_START":"2018-05-02 16:09:59"}]},

  {"NINJAOPS_EVENT_COLLECTION":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_EC_ID":"43",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"46"}]},
  {"NINJAOPS_DIAGNOSIS":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_DIG_ID":"7",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"46",},

              {
                    "NINJAOPS_DIG_ID":"5",
                    "NINJAOPS_REF":"46",
                    "BABYLON_REF":"4185",
                    "PERCENTAGE_MATCH":"91.845",
               }]},

  {"NINJAOPS_DECISION":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_DEC_ID":"3",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"46",
        "BABYLON_REF":"8439",
        "DECISION_START":"2014-06-25 22:35:00",
        "DECISION_END":"2014-06-25 22:54:00",
        "DECISION_STATUS":"1"},

        {
        "NINJAOPS_DEC_ID":"2",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"46",
        "BABYLON_REF":"8440",
        "DECISION_START":"2014-06-25 22:34:00",
        "DECISION_END":"2014-06-25 22:34:05",
        "DECISION_STATUS":"2"
        }]},

  {"NINJAOPS_REMEDIATION_AI":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_REMEDI_AI_ID":"2",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"46",
        "BABYLON_REF":"8440",
        "PERCENTAGE_MATCH":"75.000"}]}
]},

{"47":
[{"NINJAOPS_MASTER":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_ID":"47",
        "BABYLON_REF":"8548",
        "EVENT_COLLECTION_STATUS":"1"
        }]},

  {"NINJAOPS_EVENT_COLLECTION":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_EC_ID":"39",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"47",
        }]},

  {"NINJAOPS_DIAGNOSIS":
        [{
        "NINJAOPS_DIG_ID":"24",
        "NINJAOPS_REF":"47",
        "BABYLON_REF":"4077",
        "PERCENTAGE_MATCH":"89.185",
        },
              {
              "NINJAOPS_DIG_ID":"26",
              "NINJAOPS_REF":"47",
              "BABYLON_REF":"4079",
              "PERCENTAGE_MATCH":"89.185"
              },
              {
              "NINJAOPS_DIG_ID":"23",
              "NINJAOPS_REF":"47",
              "BABYLON_REF":"4186",
              "PERCENTAGE_MATCH":"89.185",
              },
              {
              "NINJAOPS_DIG_ID":"25",
              "NINJAOPS_REF":"47",
              "BABYLON_REF":"4187",
              "PERCENTAGE_MATCH":"89.185",
              }]},

  {"NINJAOPS_DECISION":[]},
  {"NINJAOPS_REMEDIATION_AI":[]}]},
  ]
```

Thank you for your help, if you have any idea of how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*ngFor="let incident of incidents.slice().reverse()
```

This will reverse your array of data.
Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow angular external module to perform sorting operation.

[ngx-order-pipe](https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe)

[Demo](https://vadimdez.github.io/ngx-order-pipe/)

Hope this answer is help to you